# Update ViewModel when something is added to a list

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, viewmodel

I am working on a windows phone 8.0 app in C# using the LongListSelector.  When I add an item to the list, there is no change on screen.  Using the following example, if I try mylist.Add(new MyList( "name", "address") that is added to my list but is not shown in the LongListSelector.  So how do I update the LongListSelector?

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<> mylist { get; set; }
}

public class MyList
{
    string name { get; set; }
    string address { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an `ObservableCollection<>` instead of the `List<>`.  The runtime framework is aware of the `ObservableCollection<>` type, and your view will (behind the scenes) subscribe to its [`CollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms653375(v=vs.105).aspx) event and update itself when you add or remove items.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MyList> mylist { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I had tried this before and it didn't work, but it was because I would add new information by creating a new list (mylist = new....). tHanks